# Bluetooth earbuds does not work after configurating dual-boot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, dualboot, ubuntu-22.04, windows-11-v22h2

(update 2023-10-02 UTC 02:17)

I have found the below solution(updated at 2023-10-01 UTC 17:10) is only effective when the PC is shutdowned and booted with removing all cables connected to the PC, not just rebooted or hibernation.

And it's effective when I backup the below key including all subkeys
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices\(MAC address)\ServicesFor(MAC address)

---

(update 2023-10-01 UTC 17:10)

I have found the temporary solution. Of cource, I don't know exactly how the solution works.

I backup the issued device registry including all subkeys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices\(MAC address)

When the trouble suddenly occur, I recover the key and reboot, then the device works again.

---

(update 2023-09-30 UTC 11:58)

It's still not solved.

After several rebooting, suddenly, the only bluetooth earbud not keyboard stops working with paring state.

I thought the problem was resolved but couldn't track it accurately. (Until the trouble occur again, I just watched YouTube, read PDF, wrote word files and typed python codes.)

---

(update 2023-09-30 UTC 06:18)

I finally solve this trouble, but I don't how that works.

Originally the solution I found at the below site does not work.
https://gist.github.com/madkoding/f3cfd3742546d5c99131fd19ca267fd4

But It works when I delete all bluetooth devices on Windows and Ubuntu, and delete all registry related with bluetooth devices that is located at the below directory on regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices

I guess the reason how that works is that makes all bluetooth setting initialized.

I'm not sure about this method, thus, if someone would try this, I recommend to back up the registry, first.

---

### In Trouble

- Bluetooth earbuds are not connected both on Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 after configurating dual-boot system
- After removing the partition where Ubuntu installed, still bluetooth earbuds are not connected

### Not In Trouble

- Not all bluetooth devices undergo this issue. (i.e. bluetooth keyboards are conneted well.)

### Ineffective Trying

- Re-installing bluetooth driver for windows
- Before installing Ubuntu, removing all bluetooth devices.
- Using Blueman
- (update 2023-09-30 UTC 00:58) Bluetooth key binding (refered by https://gist.github.com/madkoding/f3cfd3742546d5c99131fd19ca267fd4)

### System

- Windows 11 Education 22H2 build 22621.2283
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QM-HZ249
- AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS
- NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3060 Mobile

### Notes

- Drivers of network, bluetooth, graphic, souds are provided by the lastest version of the laptop manufacturer
- As the above 'In Trouble', the issue continues after removing Ubuntu. Howerver, if I delete paring of bluetooth earbuds, re-install the bluetooth driver given by the, laptop manufacturer, and reboot the laptop, then the connection may return normally. The reason I say 'may' is that sometimes, it does not work.
- (update 2023-09-29 UTC 10:59) I found that if I do not touch any bluetooth setting on Ubuntu, then bluetooth earbuds are worked well on Windows. However, in this case, earbuds are not found on Ubuntu never. The Earbud is completely confined to Windows.
- (update 2023-09-30 UTC 00:58) When I remove the bluetooth device on both Windows and Ubuntu totally and install the device only one OS, then I can use it. If I want to change the OS, I should remove the device again like the former.

I used to be a Windows-only user. Back then, Bluetooth earbuds worked perfectly, as expected. **However, after installing Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration, Bluetooth earbuds stopped working not only on Ubuntu but also on Windows.**

Interestingly, this issue occurs only with bluetooth earbuds. Bluetooth keyboards work well on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Just pairing with Bluetooth earbuds works on both Windows and Ubuntu. However, when attempting to connect on both operating systems, the connection either fails, or even if connected, the earbuds are not recognized as an output sound device.

Especially on Ubuntu, the connection is automatically disconnected shortly after being established. If a connection is tried by Blueman, the message 'br-connection-create-socket' occurs. Importantly, in both operating systems, it is impossible to output sound through the Bluetooth earbuds

I first installed Windows and then, by shrinking the volume of the Windows partition, installed Ubuntu in the remaining space.

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but I installed wireless, Bluetooth, graphics, and sound drivers using the latest drivers provided by the laptop manufacturer, rather than the latest generic drivers.

I'm looking forward to your response. Thank you for reading.